# Mission Control Application Windows Not Updating

Tags: macos, mission-control

I have Yosemite 10.11.3 running.

While using some Apple applications, when I hit the shortcut for Mission Control:Application Windows it shows the currently open windows and some recently closed ones at the bottom of the screen as thumbnails.

The problem I am having is the thumbnails for the recently closed documents is not updating and showing the most recent documents. I beleive it should reflect the "Recent Items" menu order.

Does anyone know how to reset this or clear these thumbnails and start over?

*Note: I am not talking about resetting the Recent Items menu or the system preferences for recent items. These thumbnails only appear with certain Apple applications. It is the thumbnails I am talking about.*

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Through experimentation, I have learned this:

If you clear the recent items menu on an applications "File" menu these preview thumbnails remain along with recent items when you right-click on the applications icon in the Dock.

However, if you then "killall Dock" from the terminal both the preview thumbnails and the right-click menu in the Dock get cleared. I believe if you were to log out and back in or restart they would also be cleared.

I am speculating here, but it is possible if you clear the recent menu and wait a day there may be a cleanup script that runs and resets the preview thumbnails and the right-click icon menu.

Hopefully, this is helpful to someone else that finds this behavior irritating.